# Lubuntu 14.04 suspend just logs out

Tags: lubuntu, suspend

Hi I'm running lubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Whenever I try to suspend using the log out menu it just takes me to the login screen. Clicking suspend from the login screen doesn't do anything. How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you log again with the user you given during the installation process. Be careful that normaly the Nums lock is not activated at this time.

Comment: Look up the location of the `pm-suspend ` log and post its output. I can't remember where it is right now or I world tell you